# DNN custom authentication provider using external cookie

Tags: forms-authentication, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

We are using DNN 6.2 with form authentication, we have a requirement like we need authenticate using external cookie instead of form authentication cookie. But all the existing user and their profiles are already available in DNN.

Please share any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a new login module copying the existing one, and at the top of login event just check cookie and do `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthenticationCookie(username)` and you are done!

You need to re-think in terms of security and make sure you want to do it. Instead of using cookie, you can do a url login where you have to do following:
Generate a url like /yourpage.aspx?user={bacd}&signature={hashcode of secret+username}

In yourpage.aspx you need to regenerate the signature using secret+username and match it, if it matches, just do `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthenticationCookie(username)` and redirect to appropriate page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why we go with external cookie is we need to do like SSO authentication between another site which runs in PHP. If we click a link from PHP site, without (username, pwd - login page) we need to login in our DNN site.